# SQL query to get Rows values to a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am looking for a SQL query to get sql row data to a column.

SQL Table Data

```
CustomerId     Name             Type        FoodName
=============   =============   =========   ==========
C0001           Thomas          BREAKFAST   Milk
C0001           Thomas          BREAKFAST   Bread
C0001           Thomas          BREAKFAST   Egg
C0001           Thomas          LUNCH       Rice
C0001           Thomas          LUNCH       Fish Curry
C0001           Thomas          LUNCH       Lessy
C0002           JOSEPH          BREAKFAST   Bread
C0002           JOSEPH          BREAKFAST   Jam
C0002           JOSEPH          BREAKFAST   Tea
```

The above is the SQL Table Data and I need this data in following format. Can anybody help me to create a SQL Qyery to get below output ?

```
CustomerId      Name            BREAKFAST           LUNCH   
============    =============   ================    ========== 
C0001           Thomas          Milk, Bread, Egg    Rice, Fish Curry, Lessy 
C0002           JOSEPH          Tea,Bread, Jam
```

Please help me to create SQL Query to get the above output.

I Tried the following query

```
with DietList(CustomerId,Name,BREAKFAST, DINNER) as
(
select distinct CustomerId 'CustomerId', Name as 'Name'
,(
    select a.foodName + ',' as [text()] from

    (select AdmnNo,foodName from DietCard) as a    

    where c.CustomerId = a.CustomerId and c.DietSchedule = 'BREAKFAST' and  convert(varchar, [c.ScheduleDate], 112) = '20180402' 
    for xml path('')    
    ) 'EVENINGTEA'
from DietCard 
)
,(
    select a.foodName + ',' as [text()] from

    (select AdmnNo,foodName from DietCard) as a    

    where c.CustomerId = a.CustomerId and c.DietSchedule = 'DINNER' and  convert(varchar, [c.ScheduleDate], 112) = '20180402' 
    for xml path('')    
    ) 'DINNER'
from DietCard 
)
select * from DietListList where BREAKFAST is not null or DINNER is not null
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I tries https://forums.asp.net/t/1740188.aspx?Row+Values+in+a+Column but not getting my result.

Comment: But what was the SQL you actually wrote? Can you put that into your question please?

Comment: Might want to also add which version of SQL Server you're on so that we have all the information needed to help out.

Comment: I am using SQL 2012

Comment: This question is duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798930/pivot-and-comma-separated-value

Comment: Answer added here: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/49611871/5522140`

Comment: Can you give query with creating a function ?

Comment: @user1460901 I have added my answer using cte at: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49613343/9236062

Comment: @user1460901 Hi find the sultion for your requirement by following this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/422b7/2

Comment: You should ask a new question if you are having trouble with the code in the duplicate question. Adding another unrelated topic here is not likely to get this question reopened.