# T-SQL :: List all tables, columns and pivot content

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, classification, pivot-table

I'm using the SSMS tool [Data Discovery and Classification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-data-discovery-and-classification?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=t-sql).

The tool automatically search for columns name like `%address%`, `%name%`, `%surname%`, `%e-mail%`, `%tax%`, `%zip%`, etc...
and nicely suggests you what it **might be** a sensible data.

The fact is that outside from Anglo-Saxon societies the column name is not in English but it can be in French, Spanish, Italian, etc..

So I found a query that could help me out list sensible data based on my language:

```
SELECT schema_name(tab.schema_id) AS schema_name
    ,tab.name AS table_name
    ,col.name AS column_name
    ,t.name AS data_type
    ,NULL as Data_Preview
FROM sys.tables AS tab
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS col ON tab.object_id = col.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.types AS t ON col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
ORDER BY schema_name
    ,table_name
    ,column_id;
```

Very nice.

But it would be better if I could add a last column called `Content` that `PIVOT` the content of each column and `SELECT TOP 5` of each one and nicely print it in the last column.

Can you help me archive that?

That would be a DYO Data Discovery and Classification.

**EDIT: I might have expressed myself badly.**

I'm running mz query against AdventureWorks2019:

| schema_name | table_name | column_name | data_type | Data_Preview |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person | Address | AddressID | int | NULL |
| Person | Address | AddressLine1 | nvarchar | NULL |
| Person | Address | AddressLine2 | nvarchar | NULL |
| Person | Address | City | nvarchar | NULL |
| Person | Address | StateProvinceID | int | NULL |
| Person | Address | PostalCode | nvarchar | NULL |

I want to `PIVOT` the content of each column (let's say the `TOP 5`) tho the last column

| schema_name | table_name | column_name | data_type | Data_Preview |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person | Address | AddressID | int | 1,2,3,4,5 |
| Person | Address | AddressLine1 | nvarchar | 1970 Napa Ct.,9833 Mt. Dias Blv.,7484 Roundtree Drive,9539 Glenside Dr,1226 Shoe St. |
| Person | Address | AddressLine2 | nvarchar | NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL |
| Person | Address | City | nvarchar | Bothell,Bothell,Bothell,Bothell,Bothell |
| Person | Address | StateProvinceID | int | 79,79,79,79,79 |
| Person | Address | PostalCode | nvarchar | 98011,98011,98011,98011,98011 |

Each data can be separated by a coma or whatever. The result is that I want to have a preview of the data that is actually in the column:

[image]

This guys apparently arrived to archive that:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/285445/how-to-get-column-values-in-one-comma-separated-va.html
- [Pivot and comma Separated value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798930/pivot-and-comma-separated-value)
- https://www.mikekale.com/rows-to-comma-separated-lists-in-sql-server/

Thank you

Comment: What would really help here is if you could provide an example table with a few rows of sample data and the desired output based on your sample data.

Comment: Hi @SeanLange, I updated my question. Thank you

Comment: You are going to have to use dynamic sql for this. I didn't look closely at the solution posted by Nav but that seems likely to be what you need.

Comment: FYI, the tool is looking for **sensitive** data, not sensible data. I doubt the tool as any idea if the data in your database is sensible. A tool that detects sensible data (or perhaps non-sensible data) would likely be checking your columns have the right data type, such as storing a phone number in a `varchar` or a date in an `int`; neither of which are sensible.

Comment: Also, the bounty description is wrong, `STUFF` doesn't do anything other than replace one part of a string with another. The "magic" is done by `FOR XML PATH`; all `STUFF` does in such solutions is remove the first delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to support 2016

[image]

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ColumnsToDisplay

SELECT    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY tab.name) AS Iteration,
          s.name AS SchemaName,
          tab.name AS table_name,
          col.column_id,
          col.name AS column_name,
          t.name AS data_type,
          col.max_length,
          col.precision AS PrecisionNumber,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS DataSample
INTO      #ColumnsToDisplay
FROM      sys.tables AS tab
JOIN      sys.schemas AS s
    ON    s.schema_id = tab.schema_id
JOIN      sys.columns AS col
    ON    col.object_id = tab.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.types AS t
    ON    col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
     
DECLARE @Iterations       INT = 0,
        @CurrentIteration INT = 1;

SELECT @Iterations = MAX (Iteration)
FROM   #ColumnsToDisplay

WHILE @CurrentIteration <= @Iterations
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentTableName  VARCHAR(100)   = '',
            @CurrentColumnName VARCHAR(100)   = '',
            @DynamicQuery      NVARCHAR(1000) = N''
    DECLARE @Sample VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @CurrentTableName = '';
    SET @DynamicQuery = N'';
    SELECT @CurrentTableName = CONCAT (ttq.SchemaName, '.', ttq.table_name),
           @CurrentColumnName = ttq.column_name
    FROM   #ColumnsToDisplay AS ttq
    WHERE  ttq.Iteration = @CurrentIteration

    IF (@CurrentTableName = '')
    BEGIN
        SET @CurrentIteration += 1

        CONTINUE
    END

 -- SQL Server 2019
 -- SET @DynamicQuery = CONCAT (N'
 --       SELECT @Sample = STRING_AGG(t.ColumnData,'', '') 
 --       FROM (
 --               SELECT TOP 5  CAST(x.[', @CurrentColumnName, '] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ColumnData 
 --               FROM ', @CurrentTableName, ' AS x 
 --               WHERE x.[', @CurrentColumnName, '] IS NOT NULL
 --       )t')

 -- SQL Server 2016 and lower where Stuff is supported   
    SET @DynamicQuery = CONCAT (N'
    SELECT @Sample =  STUFF((SELECT '', ''+ t.ColumnData  
    FROM (
            SELECT TOP 5 CAST(x.[', @CurrentColumnName, '] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ColumnData 
            FROM ', @CurrentTableName, ' AS x 
            WHERE x.[', @CurrentColumnName, '] IS NOT NULL 
    ) AS t
       FOR XML PATH('''')),1,1,'''')')
        
    EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @DynamicQuery,
                              N'@Sample VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
                              @Sample = @Sample OUTPUT

    UPDATE #ColumnsToDisplay
    SET    DataSample = @Sample
    WHERE  Iteration = @CurrentIteration

    SET @CurrentIteration += 1
END

SELECT ctd.Iteration,
       ctd.SchemaName,
       ctd.table_name,
       ctd.column_id,
       ctd.column_name,
       ctd.data_type,
       ctd.max_length,
       ctd.PrecisionNumber,
       ctd.DataSample
FROM   #ColumnsToDisplay AS ctd
```

Comment: Thank you @Nav, but what I need is much easier. I have expressed myself badly. I have now updated my question. Thank you

Comment: your code completes but where I can SELECT the results?

Comment: Sorry i missed a select statement at the bottom
SELECT * from #TablesToQuery

Comment: The table is still empty

Comment: I Saw the examples you shared. If you want all columns of a particular table with  data aggregation we can tweak the query to do that. I'll try and update my answer

Comment: I used DisplayName as column name with the data i had. you  might need to try a column name you have in your DB. I'll update my code based on your updates

Comment: From the screenshot it really looks is what I want but unfortunately it returns me an empty table. If I use AdventureWorks and I use `DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(50) = 'Production.Product'` it still returns me an empty table. Can you try to run your code on AdventureWorks?

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have it in my local. I'll try to do it today. And I updated the above query to do a aggregate by column name per table name given.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani I restored the AdventureWorks2019 and ran my query against it. Output is Shown in the image. Updated the Query for your use.  It ran well. hope it works for you.

Comment: It works @Nav, but why using `@TableName`? I tried to remove that but is giving me troubles like `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Schema'.`. The idea is to replace the Data  Discovery and Classification and run it in bulk for the whole database. I cannot keep changing the table name if I have 100 tables. Thank you

Comment: So strange, if I remove `DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = 'Product'` and `WHERE     tab.name = @TableName` the query is completed with errors. but then if I execute `select * from #ColumnsToDisplay` the results that I wanted are there. Thank you so much for your help. I still don't understand how to make it run smoothly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239392/discussion-between-francesco-mantovani-and-nav).

Comment: I tried to modify your code to make it available for SQL Server 2016 following this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/285445/how-to-get-column-values-in-one-comma-separated-va.html .
`    SET @DynamicQuery = CONCAT (N'
    SELECT @Sample = STUFF((SELECT t.ColumnData,'', ''
    FROM (
            SELECT TOP 5  CAST(x.', @CurrentColumnName, ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ColumnData 
            FROM ', @CurrentTableName, ' AS x 
            WHERE x.', @CurrentColumnName, ' IS NOT NULL
            FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, ''))t')`

Comment: The code is unfortunately not working :(

Comment: The errors were caused by column names like Schema_name, Primary, Database etc.. which are key words in SQL. Dynamic sql does not understand that so i made a simple tweak to wrap column names by [ set brackets] -> [Primary] which will be treated as a non key word. it works

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani Updated the Query to give all table output. And Will chat further. Just posted the comment above for clarity

Comment: Updated the query to support sql server 2016

Comment: @Nav, use `QUOTENAME` rather than concatenating brackets to enclose columns. That will handle brackets in identifiers.

Comment: Good to know. The query works as is. But Will definitely try that in my works. Thanks