# Port STRING_AGG to FOR XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, for-xml-path, string-agg

I'm currently working on [Data Discovery and Classification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-data-discovery-and-classification?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=t-sql) and I have a [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70006750/t-sql-list-all-tables-columns-and-pivot-content) that allows me to see a preview of the data while doing the classification.

This is an example of how it works against AdventureWorks:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = 'Product'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ColumnsToDisplay

SELECT    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY tab.name) AS Iteration,
          SCHEMA_NAME (tab.schema_id) AS schema_name,
          tab.name AS table_name,
          --col.column_id,
          col.name AS column_name,
          --t.name AS data_type,
          --col.max_length,
          --col.precision,
          CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS DataSample
INTO      #ColumnsToDisplay
FROM      sys.tables AS tab
JOIN      sys.columns AS col
    ON    col.object_id = tab.object_id
--LEFT JOIN sys.types AS t
--    ON    col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE     tab.name = @TableName

DECLARE @Iterations       INT = 0,
        @CurrentIteration INT = 1;

SELECT @Iterations = MAX (Iteration)
FROM   #ColumnsToDisplay 
WHILE @CurrentIteration <= @Iterations
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentTableName  VARCHAR(100)   = '',
            @CurrentColumnName VARCHAR(100)   = '',
            @DynamicQuery      NVARCHAR(1000) = N''
    DECLARE @Sample VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @CurrentTableName = '';
    SET @DynamicQuery = N'';

    SELECT @CurrentTableName = CONCAT (ttq.schema_name, '.', ttq.table_name),
           @CurrentColumnName = ttq.column_name
    FROM   #ColumnsToDisplay AS ttq
    WHERE  ttq.Iteration = @CurrentIteration

    IF (@CurrentTableName = '')
    BEGIN
        SET @CurrentIteration += 1

        CONTINUE
    END

    SET @DynamicQuery = CONCAT (N'
    SELECT @Sample = STRING_AGG(t.ColumnData,'', '') 
    FROM (
            SELECT TOP 5  CAST(x.', @CurrentColumnName, ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ColumnData 
            FROM ', @CurrentTableName, ' AS x 
            WHERE x.', @CurrentColumnName, ' IS NOT NULL
    )t')

    EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @DynamicQuery,
                              N'@Sample VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
                              @Sample = @Sample OUTPUT

    UPDATE #ColumnsToDisplay
    SET    DataSample = @Sample
    WHERE  Iteration = @CurrentIteration

    SET @CurrentIteration += 1
END

SELECT ctd.Iteration,
       ctd.schema_name,
       ctd.table_name,
       --ctd.column_id,
       ctd.column_name,
       --ctd.data_type,
       --ctd.max_length,
       --ctd.precision,
       ctd.DataSample
FROM   #ColumnsToDisplay AS ctd
```

Here the result:

| Iteration | schema_name | table_name | column_name | DataSample |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Production | Product | ProductID | 980, 365, 771, 404, 977 |
| 2 | Production | Product | Name | Adjustable Race, All-Purpose Bike Stand, AWC Logo Cap, BB Ball Bearing, Bearing Ball |
| 3 | Production | Product | ProductNumber | AR-5381, BA-8327, BB-7421, BB-8107, BB-9108 |
| 4 | Production | Product | MakeFlag | 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 |
| 5 | Production | Product | FinishedGoodsFlag | 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 |
| 6 | Production | Product | Color | Black, Black, Black, Silver, Silver |

The problem is that this query only works from SQL Server 2017 and above because it uses `STRING_AGG`. For SQL Server 2016 and below I'm supposed to use `STUFF` instead.

I followed this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/285445/how-to-get-column-values-in-one-comma-separated-va.html) but I couldn't really fix it.

The only thing I know is that the part of the code that I need to port is this:

```
SET @DynamicQuery = CONCAT (N'
SELECT @Sample = STRING_AGG(t.ColumnData,'', '') 
FROM (
        SELECT TOP 5  CAST(x.', @CurrentColumnName, ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ColumnData 
        FROM ', @CurrentTableName, ' AS x 
        WHERE x.', @CurrentColumnName, ' IS NOT NULL
)t')
```

Can anyone help me port `STRING_AGG` to `STUFF`?

Thank you

Comment: `Stuff` is actually not relevant and only used to remove the superfluous suffixed delimiters, there are an innumerable examples of how to use `for xml` to aggregate strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String_agg for SQL Server before 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-before-2017)

Comment: See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207371/please-explain-what-does-for-xml-path-type-value-nvarcharmax) for details of using XML for aggregate string concatenation.

Comment: Side point: you have an injection risk. `CONCAT (ttq.schema_name, '.', ttq.table_name)` should be `CONCAT (QUOTENAME(ttq.schema_name), '.', QUOTENAME(ttq.table_name))` and `@CurrentColumnName` should be `QUOTENAME(@CurrentColumnName)`

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface , but this code will not be part of any application, I will just ruin it with my hands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Than you for your help.

The right question was:

```
SET @DynamicQuery = CONCAT (N'
SELECT @Sample =  STUFF((SELECT '', ''+ t.ColumnData  
FROM (
        SELECT TOP 5 CAST(x.[', @CurrentColumnName, '] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ColumnData 
        FROM ', @CurrentTableName, ' AS x 
        WHERE x.[', @CurrentColumnName, '] IS NOT NULL 
) AS t
   FOR XML PATH('''')),1,1,'''')')
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's clarify that `stuff` is, as Stu mentions, just used to remove the first delimiter.
So, if you had

```
'a','b','c'
```

and you wanted to use a commas delimiter, xml path would give you:

```
,a,b,c
```

and you use stuff to cut off the first comma:

```
a,b,c
```

Your query seems to have no delimiters at all, so you won't use `stuff`. With that out of the picture, here's me *untested* guess, it's tricky what with the dynamic query added on top of it:

```
SET @DynamicQuery = CONCAT (N'
    set @Sample =
            ( 
                select t.ColumnData
                from ', @CurrentTableName, ' AS x 
                where x.', @CurrentColumnName, ' IS NOT NULL
                for xml path(''''), type
            ).value(''.'',''nvarchar(max)'')
)t')
```

Comment: strange, it says `(1 row affected)
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: `print` it maybe?